# Error estimates of power series $ \left| f(x) - \sum_{n=0}^k a_n(x-x_0)^n \right| \leq \left(\frac{r}{R_1} \right)^{k+1} \frac{R_1}{R_1-r} $

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $f(x)=\sum a_n(x-x_0)^n$ has a radius of convergence $R$ and $0<r<R_1<R$. Show that there is an integer $k_0$ such that $$ \left| f(x) - \sum_{n=0}^k a_n(x-x_0)^n \right| \leq \left(\frac{r}{R_1} \right)^{k+1} \frac{R_1}{R_1-r} $$
>   if $|x-x_0| \leq r$ and $k \geq k_0$.

I have to admit I am a bit lost to approach this problem. What is the best way to proceed?

If this problem is impossible, How would you prove that no integer $k$ can exist in this configuration?

any input/help is much appreciated.

Comment: So It seems that this problem resolution is impossible. It is a direct quote from a book. I will put a bounty in 1 day to call a final attention.

Comment: "$k\ge k$" doesn't make much sense. I'm pretty sure some of your $k$'s are supposed to be different letters. Maybe some are lowercase $k$ and some are uppercase $K$? Please correct the problem -- once it becomes meaningful, it would be a lot easier to think of a solution to it.

Comment: @JohnMa: The question doesn't assert that it has to be true independently of the function. If you change $f$, then the series and its radius of convergence $R$ will change -- which is not important, though, The claim is that there exists such a $k$, but it clearly depends on the function, the series, the radius $R$, and the chosen values of $R_1$ and $r$ -- the latter two being the important quantities. For a new function, it may not be true with the same $k$, but it will be true with a different one.

Comment: @zipirovich I have checked over, I do not find any mistake. You can access the pdf book it is online at ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_REAL_ANALYSIS.PDF [ Exercise chap 4.5 p.276 Exercise 5 (or p.286 using adobe page number) ]

Comment: correction p.277 using adobe

Comment: I have edited your question so that it is at least answerable. I hope that is what you want to ask.

Comment: yes I agree that this $k \geq k$ made no sense. I was thinking also at $k \geq k+1$ maybe. Let's leave it with $k_0$. I still do not see how to deal with this problem. Thx for your input I hope it helps somebody to understand this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the radius of convergence is $R$ and $R_1 <R$. Thus $f$ is absolutely convergent when $|x-x_0|\le R_1$. In particular, when $|x-x_0| = R_1$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n| R_1^n <\infty \Rightarrow |a_n | R_1^n \to 0.$$

Thus there is $k_0$ so that $|a_n| \le R_1^{-n}$ for all $n\ge k_0$. Now for all $r<R_1$ and $|x-x_0|\le r$, if $k \ge k_0$,

$$\begin{split}
\left| f(x) - \sum_{n=0}^k a_n (x-x_0)^n\right| &= \left| \sum_{n=k+1}a_n (x-x_0)^n\right|\\
&\le \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty |a_n| |x-x_0|^n \\
&\le \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty R_1^{-n} r^n \\
&= \left(\frac{r}{R_1}\right)^{k+1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{r}{R_1}\right)^n \\
&=\left(\frac{r}{R_1}\right)^{k+1} \frac{1}{1-(r/R_1)} \\
&=\left(\frac{r}{R_1}\right)^{k+1} \frac{R_1}{R_1 -r}. 
\end{split}$$

Comment: Nice demonstration Very clear. Just a question : Could you elaborate on the argumentation that since $|a_n| R_1^n \rightarrow 0$ one can state that $|a_n| \leq R_1^n$?

Comment: If a sequence $s_n$ converges to zero, then for some $ k_0$ we have $|s_n|\le 1$ for all $n\ge k_0$. @gegu